# Embarrasing paralellizing a process Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I have to compute a lot of integrals (more or less 8 million), which requires access to some coefficients, taking 15 Gb of ram. If I let the computation on its own it takes 24 hours, and in order to do it faster up to date I have been just taking chunks of integrals and running them on different notebooks, but this is "wasting" ram, as I would just be loading 'N' times the same information, where N is the number of notebooks that I am launching.

I am sure there should be an option for computing this faster. I have tried with p.map from the multiprocessing library in python but I have not been successful.

I have 16 CPUs available and a lot of RAM, but the computer I'm using is shared with other two users and I don't want to be wasting RAM for everyone.

Comment: multiprocessing will most likely be the way to go, unless someone here can work out some GPU compute magic which might also be an option given the scale. Do you have any sample code for what you've tried? Why wasn't it successful?

Comment: what did you try? Show your code. You could also show example data.

Comment: You might also want to look at `numba` from the `PyPi` repository or a different programming language.